# STM32 Memory Dump and Extracting Secret Key

Tags: memory, embedded, stm32, reverse-engineering

I am quite new at embedded development and started with a STM32F429 board to improve myself.

I have just developed a basic Caesar encryption application for my board. It is working well, and defined the secret key as "3". Now I would like to extract this super secret(!) key from my device.

1. How can I do it? Should I dump the memory or firmware of my device, and how?
2. May you suggest me any software for this proccess? (Not ST Utility or STM softwares please. Because I would like to try gained experiences on other devices as well.)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean dump or extract key? Where do you want to have this key? Do you want to send it to PC? Because as far as I can tell now, if your program on MCU has a key (or any other piece of data), you can send it via any peripheral? Like I2C, SPI, QUADSPI, UART? Whatever you do with it? So I'm not exactly seeing a problem. If you want to read MCU Flash or SDRAM of MCU, you can always do that since they're memory mapped to specific memory regions (may or may not need memory protection unit activated for that)

Comment: @Ilya I have defined a variable which includes the key. So, I would like to access this key as a 3rd person. I can also do it by ST Utility program but I do not want to STM softwares. I am looking for a solution which will work on almost all MCUs. Yes, as I understand I need to read the flash memory but I do not know how can I do it.

Comment: If you created a variable, this variable is in RAM. You just send it via I2C (or anything else) like you would send any other random piece of data? I mean, technically, you don't need to read Flash at all. But if you want to, Reference Manual of the MCU has a whole "Flash" section, which deals specifically with all operations on the internal Flash, including reading any specific byte you want. Can be a little overwhelming at first, but it will get more understandable the further you read. By default flash is memory mapped onto 0x00000000. So you can read directly from flash address.

Comment: @Ilya I achieved to read the flash memory by OpenOCD, it was including some values I defined to variables. However, I could not see my function and the parameter I passed to that function. So, as I understand I need to read RAM, right? So, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm still wondering, what stops you from sending that value out over I2C? I mean, you can change the code, right? Or am I misinterpreting situation?

Comment: @Ilya I am trying to inspect my device as a third person, like reverse engineering. I want to extract the key as if it is not my device. Briefly, I need to gain experience on reversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it the value you're looking for is hardcoded. In that case it resides in the internal flash. So yes, a memory dump will be necessary.

I will go the long way and assume that you know very little about how it works, so if you know some of this stuff, well, good for you. I will try to give a few pointers.

Specifically about STM32:
You have an option to boot the microcontroller from the so-called system memory, which is read-only memory, and it is already preprogrammed from factory with a bootloader. You can talk to that running bootloader via UART (most common way, comes with ST-Link, but any cheapo USB-UART bridge also works). Or it can be some other protocol. You can ask that bootloader to read its flash out to you, among other things. This is covered in [AN2606.pdf](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf). It has some useful links in it, such as:

[image]

names of documents, where you can find specific bootloader commands for any interface you wish. Of course, you only care about interfaces, that the bootloader of your specific MCU F429 supports, which are found in the same AN2606, page 172 (for bootloader version 0.7, there is also 0.9 for those MCUs, I have no idea how to tell which one you have, so...try? UART configuration seems identical anyway):

[image]

So what exactly needs to be done? Flip the state of BOOT0 pin - permanently - of the MCU and reset it (power cycle or reset pin, both ok). You will boot the MCU into bootloader instead of booting program from flash. You can read about it in the [Reference manual STM32F429](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), page 69. It talks about states of BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins on boot. What pins are boot0 - if they're not marked on your board, then you'll have to consult [F429 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00071990.pdf), page 69 (I swear, it's a coincidence). Depending on your specific IC, it will be one pin or another.

It will activate all MCUs peripherals as per docs above and it and wait on its UART and other pins for commands. Commands listed in the documents I provided above. Let's take a look at [AN3155](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3155-usart-protocol-used-in-the-stm32-bootloader-stmicroelectronics.pdf) about USART of bootloader:

[image]

And the commands are

[image]

are all in that document, the table of contents in pdf really helps to find stuff quickly. Of course, if you need specific details, and you will need specific information about specific commands, it's all in there too. How many bytes in command, how many bytes at a time you read from flash etc. Basically, you can either write your own program that does that (even program another microcontroller to program that microcontroller using victim's bootloader), or use any other software that knows what commands to send to the bootloader. It can be ST utility, it can be any other program. They all implement the very same command set, so it doesn't actually matter much. I couldn't find many programs that do that, the only thing that stood out was stm32flash. Never used it myself. I'm ok with ST stuff, since I know what it does (I think).

Oh yeah back to getting the secret value out. I almost forgot about that. Well, then you open the dump in hex viewer/editor, and scroll it around looking for interesting combination of values. Yeah, that's kinda what it looks like. One can run it via disassembly. Scroll disassembled code around, see if there are any numeric values that stand out. You know, some random number 0xD35B581 or something hardcoded in the middle of pretty program could mean something, like be a serial number or a secret number. Unfortunately, I'm reaching boundaries of my competence here, so won't go any further on what one can do with dump.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I also recommend to use OpenOCD and Radare2 tools, so I could dump the memory. However I could not see my secret key (3) in the dump, its probably because so short and not stored in the memory. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: well, if it's not stored in the memory, you won't find it in the dump. How exactly and where exactly is the value located? How is it declared? Is it a global variable? Is it created with code during runtime? Also don't forget that if it's a decimal value, the values shown in dump are still all HEX. So you may have simply not recognized it.